# "I saw him crossing the road", a semantic problem

Tags: ambiguity

> I saw him crossing the road.

Before, I asked a question regarding the differences between certain sentences in which "cross" and "crossing" were involved.

Now, I have a new question for which I hope no one think it is a duplicate, albeit I cannot exclude for sure this case.

Problem is that there is no parallelism between gerund and participle between English and Italian, so the sentence above can be translated in two senses:

1. the first implies that "I" is crossing the road and, during the crossing, "I" saw "him" ("l'ho visto attraversando la strada", where "attraversando" is Italian gerund);
2. the second implies that "him" is crossing the road and "I" saw "him" when "him" was crossing the road ("l'ho visto che attraversava la strada", where "che attraversava"="attraversante" is, the latter, Italian participle).

Hoping of having explained the doubts I have, can anybody explain if an English-speaker sees ambigutiy in the sentence above? Or, do I imagine things, so this is a not real question?

Comment: In Italian the difference is between _l'ho visto attraversare la strada_ and _l'ho visto attraversando la strada_. Notice that a gerund works as noun, but what in Italian is called _gerundio_ never works as noun, as you don't say _mi piace mangiando_.

Comment: Also, _che attraversava_ doesn't mean _attraversante_. _Ho visto che attraversava la strada_ in English is "I saw that he crossed the street." Where English uses the simple past, Italian can use the _passato prossimo_ (_ho visto_) or _imperfetto_ (_attraversava_).

Comment: kiam, I disagree and you should not apodictically state that "che attraversava" doesn't mean "attraversante". Just now I see a sign through the window "Il pubblico entrante e' invitato ad attraversare i tornelli", where "entrante" is present participle and, without changing in meaning, it can be replaced with "che entra". However, I'm waiting IL&U starts so that we can talk about the Italian language there.

Comment: In that case, _uscente_ is used as adjective. That doesn't mean you can always replace _che usciva_ with _uscente_; you surely cannot say _l'ho visto uscente_ instead of _l'ho visto che usciva_, and _settimana uscente_ doesn't mean _settimana che esce/usciva_.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, yes, there is certainly room for ambiguity there. I would probably guess that

> "I saw Paul crossing the road"

means that Paul was crossing, and I was somewhere nearby, but

> "Crossing the road, I saw Paul"

would probably mean I was crossing, and that's when I spotted Paul. However, *the first sentence could indeed have the second meaning*; consider it a shortened or abridged form of "I saw Paul [while I was] crossing the road."

Comment: I dunno. While I can certainly see where such a misinterpretation could come from, I would maintain that it *is* a misinterpretation: if you want to say that *you're* the one crossing the road, you have to add a "while" in there ("I saw Paul while crossing the road") or restructure it as you did in your second example.

Comment: @Martha: I agree; if a speaker wants to say, "I saw Paul while I was crossing the road," that's what the speaker would usually say. As for "I saw Paul crossing the road," that would most likely mean that Paul was the one crossing, although the alternate interpretation is still a valid one – even if it is unlikely to be what the speaker meant. Still, I could see such a construct being deliberately used in a [paraprosdokian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraprosdokian), perhaps: _I saw Paul crossing the road... and that's when the bus hit me_.